# Devilman manga and novels reading order

Tags: devilman

I have found many mangas and some novels about devilman and got confused about it and don't know where to start so can anyone help me about it.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, if we are going to go into *Devilman* and the reading order for it, we have to get into semi-spoiler territory for the ending of the original manga, so you are gonna be warned.

*Keep in mind this is predominantly for the manga*, which forms the baseline you need to have to get into this series.

- Start with the original *Devilman* series, which ran for 5 volumes. The series ends, with a time loop, and I won't go into circumstances, but it is barely touched upon in the Netflix *Crybaby* Adapation.
- *Shin Devilman* is a side story that happens sometime in between the main series, before Akira is betrayed.
- *Devilman Lady* is a series that has to deal with fallout from the events of the original series timeloop and the aftermath of it, but that comes closer to the end of this storyline.
- *Neo Devilman*, *Amon: The Darkside of Devilman*, and *Devilman: Strange Days* are "what if" and side stories that pertain to OG, SHIN, and LADY storylines.
- Lastly, we have *Demon Knight*, which is a prequel to *Devilman*, and finally *Devilman Saga*, which partially concludes it.

Go Nagai's other series, *Violence Jack*, also has ties to Devilman as well, but I won't go into that.

Ultimately, the order would be *OG, SHIN, LADY, SAGA, JACK*. Everything else (*Neo, Amon, Strange Days, Demon Knight*) can be read later.

These answers were provided from my knowledge and a bit of fact checking from [The Devilman Wikia](http://devilman.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)